# Standard paragraph following subparagraph

Tags: sectioning, lyx, sections-paragraphs

I'm a newbie using LyX and was wondering why when I put a standard paragraph after a *subparagraph it always renders the first standard paragraph after the *subparagraph on the same line?

Comment: Do you leave a blank line before the `\paragraph{...}` command? This should keep LaTeX from typesetting it on the same line as the material of the preceding `\subparagraph`.

Answer (score 4):

That's the standard behaviour for subparagraphs: the text will start in the same line as the title, and the title will be indented by `\parindent`. If you want to change the formatting, you can redefine `\subparagraph`; here's a little example of a possible redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\itshape}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Test subparagraph}\lipsum[1]
\paragraph{Test subparagraph}\lipsum[1]
\subparagraph{Test subparagraph}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Now, the title will be italicized and won't be indented; the text will start on a new line.

[image]

I, however, don't know how to implement this in LyX.

Answer (score 0):

The Code works for lyx too, just add possibly the redefinition also for the paragraph

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\itshape}}

\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\itshape}}
\makeatother
```

You have too add these lines to *Document*->*Settings*->*LaTex Preamble* 
Preview in lyx wont work, but the pdf output is just fine.

Comment: There's a typo in your answer: the redefinition for `\paragraph` should start with `\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%`